# How to cope with more than 100 IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, checkbox, excel-2007, vba

I am creating an checklist using an array of checkboxes in MS Excel 2007. Based on the number of checkboxes, there are 2^7 (=128) possible combinations in which the checkboxes can be selected.  Each combination of checkboxes selected gives a unique outcome.

**What would be the most efficient way to successfully test for each condition, and give a result in a cell in a worksheet?**

Example code:

```
=if(and(chkbox1=true,chkbox2=true,chkbox3=false,chkbox4=false,chkbox5=true,chkbox6=false,chkbox7=true),"Unique outcome",if(and(chkbox8=true,chkbox9.............)))))))))
```

The method I have (unsuccessfully) attempted is to use IF statements.  I have attempted to bypass the nested IF limit by creating 14 named ranges with approximately nine nested IFs each, and compile the 14 named ranges in a valid nested IF within the spreadsheet.  Unfortunately, the processor is struggling to calculate the outcome of this (i.e. computer is "freezing").

- Would reducing the number of nested IFs in the named ranges (but increasing the number of nested IFs in the spreadsheet) have an influence on efficiency?
- Would it be better to use nested IFs in cells rather than named ranges?
- Would VLOOKUP work?

At the moment, I am contemplating using VBA code as people have said that it would be the most efficient way to approach numerous conditions.  Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String together a `1` or `0` for each TRUE or FALSE result then create a lookup table with a column for each possible binary value and another column for the outcomes (or rows rather than columns).

Comment: Additionally, for a simple way to string the results together to make a binary string you can use Abs(chkbox1) & Abs(chkbox2) & etc...

Comment: Thanks pnuts.  Makes good sense but I am still uncertain.  So your method essentially defines the various combinations in the simplest way and provides a neat way to search for the outcome.  My uncertainty lies in that how will excel know what combination to look for in the vlookup table?  Does this make sense?  Will I not need to let excel know what the combination is, in order to search for it in the lookup table?  To add, this check list is supposed to simplify a decision tree type of function, giving suggested outcomes, according to the combinations selected by the operator.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, Thanks pnuts.  It finally came to me how to do it.  I am having one problem though....  any value with a leading 1, i.e. "1000000" is giving a #NA error.  I have tried to add a inverted comma (as I did with the leading zeros" but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, the lookup is returning #N/A.  1000000 is numeric in the table.  I have changed it to a 'text' format and with a leading "'", i.e. '1000000 to represent a string (I am guessing I am wrong here), with no success.  The vlookup table references the cell in which the search term is located, so I am not sure what you mean by it being in double inverted commas...

Comment: This is the code i used for the search term : {=--X31&--X32&--X37&--X38&--X33&--X34&--X35}.  Changing the format to text is not helping.

Comment: I just tried to sort the table (ascending and descending), and it seems to have corrected the initial issue (with {1000000}) but now gives the same error with all the other leading one strings (e.g. 1000010)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on pnuts's answer, you could achieve this with a formula such as:

```
=if(chkbox1=true,1,0)+if(chkbox2=true,2,0)+if(chkbox3=true,4,0)+if(chkbox4=true,8,0)+ ...
```

This will give you a value between 0 and 127 which you can then use in a `VLOOKUP` function to get the appropriate result from a two column table (or more simply, in an `OFFSET` function to get the appropriate result from a single column list).

Comment: Ooh. (Googles) Oooh. I have a workbook containing several thousand `OFFSET`s. I may be able to make some improvements to it. Thanks.